# Are there different names or references for commits?

Tags: github, commit

I cannot find the answers to these 3 questions:

- HEAD - the name for the last commit of a branch
- ???? - the name for the last commit that came from the remote repository
- ???? - the name for the last commit before a merge was started

I've looked at https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the **[git revisions](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html)** documentation:

- HEAD - The name for the last commit of a branch

> **HEAD** names the commit on which you based the changes in the working tree.

- ??? - the name for the last commit before a merge was started

> **MERGE_HEAD** records the commit(s) which you are merging into your branch when you run git merge

- ??? - the name for the last commit that came from the remote repository

> **FETCH_HEAD** records the branch which you fetched from a remote repository with your last git fetch invocation